# Should "built-up" be hyphenated or not?

Tags: writing-style, hyphenation

I have a sentence in this form:

> The product uses an example system to show how a fully featured system can be **built-up**.

It's been suggested that in this context, **built up** (without a hyphen) is more correct. I have a feeling that the difference is quite slight. I want to convey a layered approach to the design process.

If it makes a difference, this is a technical document, and intended to use American English (which is not my native language).

Comment: 'Built-up' is the attributive adjective variant. In the (at least much more) verbal 'how a system can be built up', the hyphen is inappropriate. See [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/build+up).

Comment: I think I (UK) would only hyphenate 'built-up' in the phrase 'built-up area' meaning a district that isn't rural.

Comment: @KateBunting and never for something like a paper-mache model (obviously not a model of a city)?

Comment: You would use _built-up_ when you need an adjective: a built-up reputation, built-up model of a city. Built up in your sentence is no different from saying a system can be _relied on_, _looked at_, or _finished off_, all without hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The product uses an example system to show how a fully featured system
>   can be built-up.

1. Built-up if it is an adjective describing the featured system as being made of several sections or layers fastened together (Definition here at [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/built-up))
2. If you can say the sentence without the word "up" and it still has your intended meaning, then you are likely using it as a form of the verb, build.  In this case write it without the hyphen, and if you still don't like the way it looks just simply drop the bogus "up."